# URI Routing With Dynamic value

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

This is my code in routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin";
$route['(:any)'] = $route['default_controller']."/index/";
```

This is my url:

```
http://myserver.net/visio/jklmn
```

But i cant to get the value in `index()` in `admin` controller.
I want to get the value `jklmn` in `admin` controller.If there is any mistake in my routing code.

This is my index() code;

```
function index($key = ""){
        if(isset($key)){
            $newkey = $key;
            $data['key']  = $key; 
            $this->load->view('index',$data);
        }else{
            redirect('admin/index_login');
        }

}
```

When i taking above link in browser i get the error message below:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /visio/jklmn was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this routing rule:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = $route['default_controller']."/index/$2";
```

which will match a URL with 2 segments (each containing any character) and pass the second match as `$2`.

You can also pass the first match, just use `$1`.